# Restart Mysql in RHEL 7

Tags: mysql, redhat-enterprise-linux

I am trying to restart Mysql in RHEL7

Here are the packages installed:

```
]$ yum list installed | grep mysql
rh-mysql57-lz4.x86_64                r131-7.el7        @rhel-server-rhscl-7-rpms
rh-mysql57-mecab.x86_64              0.996-1.el7.9     @rhel-server-rhscl-7-rpms
rh-mysql57-mysql.x86_64              5.7.24-1.el7      @rhel-server-rhscl-7-rpms
rh-mysql57-mysql-common.x86_64       5.7.24-1.el7      @rhel-server-rhscl-7-rpms
rh-mysql57-mysql-config.x86_64       5.7.24-1.el7      @rhel-server-rhscl-7-rpms
rh-mysql57-mysql-errmsg.x86_64       5.7.24-1.el7      @rhel-server-rhscl-7-rpms
rh-mysql57-mysql-server.x86_64       5.7.24-1.el7      @rhel-server-rhscl-7-rpms
rh-mysql57-runtime.x86_64            2.3-4.el7         @rhel-server-rhscl-7-rpms
rh-php71-php-mysqlnd.x86_64          7.1.30-2.el7      @rhel-server-rhscl-7-rpms
```

---

```
$ systemctl list-unit-files | grep mysq

rh-mysql57-mysqld.service                     enabled
rh-mysql57-mysqld@.service
```

---

```
$systemctl restart mysqld

Failed to restart mysqld.service: Unit not found.
```

---

```
$service mysqld restart

Failed to restart mysqld.service: Unit not found.
```

Can anyone point me to the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

The name of the service is rh-mysql57-mysqld.service

And you can find out all the service names by using the following command:

```
systemctl list-units --type service
```

So to restart you do:

```
$ systemctl restart rh-mysql57-mysqld.service
```